# how to change particular object value to null and rest like (val, val+1, val+2,...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have array of object `listItem`, passing parameter `paramId`

Based on condition, when the `id` in the the list is same with `paramId` and having color as `red`

then next object (current val greater than val) value should be like

value, value + 1, value + 2, value + 3...  and that current object `val` become null

how to achieve this using for.. of loop using javascript

```
example 1
var paramId = 14
const listItem = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 25, val: 3, color: 'yellow' }, 
  { id: 43, val: 5, color: 'green' },

];


Expected Output

[
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: null, color: 'red' }, // change val to null
  { id: 25, val: 2, color: 'yellow' }, // 3 becomes 2 (val)
  { id: 43, val: 3, color: 'green' }, //5 becomes 3 (val + 1)

];

example 2
var paramId = 25
const listItem = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 25, val: 3, color: 'red' }, 
  { id: 23, val: 4, color: 'green' },
  { id: 43, val: 5, color: 'green' },

];

Expected Output

[
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 25, val: null, color: 'red' }, // changes val to null
  { id: 23, val: 3, color: 'green' }, // 4 becomes 3 (val)
  { id: 43, val: 4, color: 'green' }, // 5 becomes 4 (val+1)

];
```

```
Tried


const getByIdandColor =  list.find(e=>e.id === paramId and e.color === 'red')


for (const item of listItem) {
   if(item.id === paramId && item.color === 'red') {
     ...item,
     val: null
   } else if(item.color !== 'red' && item.id >= getByIdandColor.id) {
      ...item,
     val: val +1
   }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey im not sure but i think you can handle it like that.

```
for (const item of listItem) {
  if(item.id === paramId && item.color === 'red') {
    ...item,
    item.val: null // val of what?
  } else if(item.color !== 'red' && item.id >= getByIdandColor.id) {
    ...item,
    item.val: item.val +1 // val of what?
  }
}
```

You have to call the val of the currenty item. Otherwise val will not be find and so you cant update any value of undefined ^^

Comment: thanks, as you said val cannot be find if I set first, is there any way first increment and then I set to null, Got Stuck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are not changing the value on the list, try this.

```
let oldValue;
for (const item of listItem) {
  if (item.id === paramId && item.color === "red") {
    oldValue = item.val // set old value
    const index = listItem.indexOf(item); // get the index of the current item on the list
    listItem[index] = { // change the item on the list
      ...item,
      val: null,
    };
  } else if (item.color !== "red" && item.id >= getByIdandColor.id) {
    const index = listItem.indexOf(item);

    listItem[index] = {
      ...item,
      val: oldValue,
    };
    oldValue++
  }
}
```

Comment: I think misunderstood the logic, from the list item, fetching the val === red and id === paramId, say it as currentObj will be { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'red' }, then I should update only the remaining objects say[{ id: 25, val: 3, color: 'yellow' }, 
  { id: 43, val: 5, color: 'green' }] then having val > currentobjval, by setting currentobjval to first remaining object, and increase the next final output will be ashown

Comment: not tally with expected output

Comment: not sure if I totally get it but trying to understand the example, I think that you need to keep a reference to the old value before change it. I edit my answer, plz check it

Comment: thanks , but it's not working for this scenario  https://jsfiddle.net/2p6krdqm/2/

Answer (score 0):

```js
let paramId = 25
const listItem = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 25, val: 3, color: 'red' }, 
  { id: 23, val: 4, color: 'green' },
  { id: 43, val: 5, color: 'green' },

];


const getByIdandColor =  listItem.find(e=>e.id === paramId && e.color === 'red')


let prevIndex;
const x = listItem.map((item, index)=> {
    if(item.id === paramId && item.color === 'red'){
        prevIndex = index
        return {...item, val:null}
    }
    if(item.color !== 'red' && index === prevIndex + 1){
        prevIndex = index
        return {...item, val : listItem[prevIndex].val -1}
    }
    return {...item}
})

console.log(x)
```

Comment: thanks, but scenario fails when objarr is like this `let paramId = 43
const listItem = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
  { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 25, val: 8, color: 'yl' }, 
  { id: 23, val: 7, color: 'bl' },
  { id: 43, val: 4, color: 'red' }

];`

Comment: not sure why it does not work for this scenario

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vgqjrzxL/

Comment: can u give me the output for the above scenario, it turns the val of item 43 to null.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a9be1v6w/ have added the expected output, it turns to null, but object value is not changed

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function which satisfies the expected results.
Here it goes like this.

```js
    function getLastValidValue(listArr, index) {
      // in this function we are getting last valid value from the array before given index
      let lastValidValue = null;
      for (let i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (listArr[i].val !== null) {
          lastValidValue = listArr[i].val;
          break;
        }
      }
      return lastValidValue;
    }
    
    function getExpectedOutput(listItem, id) {
      // using a blank array to store values
      const output = [];
    
      for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        // if the id and color matches we are pushing the object with null value
        if (listItem[i].id === id && listItem[i].color === 'red') {
          output.push({ ...listItem[i], val: null });
        }
        // if the id does not match and item value is null we are pushing the object as it is
        if (listItem[i].id !== id && listItem[i].val === null) {
          output.push({ ...listItem[i] });
        }
        // if the id does not match and item value is not null we are pushing the object with last valid value + 1
        if (listItem[i].id !== id && listItem[i].val !== null) {
          output.push({ ...listItem[i], val: getLastValidValue(output, i) ? getLastValidValue(output, i) + 1 : 1 });
        }
      }
      return output;
    }
    const paramId = 14;

    const listItems = [
      { id: 10, val: null, color: 'blue' },
      { id: 13, val: 1, color: 'black' },
      { id: 14, val: 2, color: 'red' },
      { id: 25, val: 3, color: 'yellow' },
      { id: 43, val: 5, color: 'green' },
    ];

    console.log(getExpectedOutput(listItems, paramId));
```